# How can I figure out how many kWh's are in a battery using the mAh's and voltage.

Tags: electricity, voltage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relating milliampere-hours to watt-hours for batteries](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/relating-milliampere-hours-to-watt-hours-for-batteries)

How can I figure out how many kWh's are in a battery using the mAh's and voltage. 
Some batteries only list mAh's and volts rather than kWh's so how can I convert between the two.